# Dangling symlinks in MacTeX 2017 ghostscript install

Tags: mactex, ghostscript

There’s a strange (semi-?) bug in my installation of [MacTeX-2017](http://www.tug.org/mactex/): there are a whole bunch of incorrectly symlinked fonts in the following directories:

```
/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.21/Resource/CIDFSubst/
/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.21/Resource/Font/
```

For example,

```
/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.21/Resource/CIDFSubst/ipaexg.ttf@ -> /Library/TeX/Root/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/ipaex/ipaexg.ttf
/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.21/Resource/Font/bchb8a.pfb@ -> /Library/TeX/Root/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/bitstrea/charter/bchb8a.pfb
```

In my installation, there is no `/Library/TeX/Root/texmf-dist/`. I think these should point to `/usr/local/texlive/2017/` rather than `/Library/TeX/Root/` (actually, that's not quite right... see the answers). Of course I can fix by hand but it’s kind of annoying…

[A perhaps related issue is that on one of my machines these symlinks got assigned to a random user (not the one who did the installation, nor root).]

Is this a bug or am I missing a subtlety?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

```
ls -l /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.21/Resource/CIDFSubst/ipam.ttf
```

yields

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 wheel  65 Jun  5 14:18 /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.21/Resource/CIDFSubst/ipam.ttf@ -> /Library/TeX/Root/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/ipaex/ipam.ttf
```

Let's try

```
ls -l /Library/TeX/Root
```

which yields

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  39 Jun  5 14:23 /Library/TeX/Root@ -> Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Root
```

OK, let's go on with

```
ls -l /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Root
```

and we finally get home:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  40 Jun  5 14:23 /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Root@ -> ../../../../../../usr/local/texlive/2017
```

No dangling link at all.

The TeX Live Utility (formerly it was the TeX Distribution control panel) can be used to change at any moment the TeX distribution, which is implemented by modifying the *last* symbolic link I showed.

If I choose Configure > Change Default TeX Live Version… and check TeX Live 2016, repeating the last command yields

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  40 Oct 31  2016 /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Root@ -> ../../../../../../usr/local/texlive/2016
```

whereas the other links are unchanged.

Comment: To be clear, the problem arose because `/Library/TeX/Root` was *not* the correct symlink in my installation (and the installer was unwilling or unable to overwrite what was there, but also didn't bother to tell me about it).

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem arose because there was a pre-existing `/Library/TeX/Root` directory --- not a symlink, but an actually directory, leftover from some very old tex distribution. Unfortunately, this didn't produce any errors that I could see from the installer. So I moved the directory aside, and then re-ran the installer, which correctly built the symlink:

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    38 19 Jul 13:56 Documentation@ -> Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Doc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    45 19 Jul 13:56 Local@ -> Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/TexmfLocal
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    39 19 Jul 13:56 Root@ -> Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Root
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    29 19 Jul 13:56 texbin@ -> Distributions/Programs/texbin
drwxr-xr-x  21 root  wheel   714  5 Jun 07:53 Distributions/
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  2469  7 Mar  2016 Choosing a TeX Distribution.rtf
```

In my case the original `Root` was filled with several empty directories, so it was no problem to delete it, but ymmv...

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the WRONG thing to do! The /Library/TeX/Root is a doubly indirect link to the root of your TeX Live Distribution. That allows it to change dynamically if you change active TeX Distributions. Those symlinks were correct.

Comment: Sorry... that was the right thing to do. However it would be much easier to simply install the FixLink2017.pkg supplied in /Applications/TeX which would do the job.

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear: the original `.../Root` was a real dir, not symlink, leftover from, I think, an ancient tex distribution.

Comment: ... and the documentation doesn't make it clear that FixLink will fix the `/Library/TeX/*` links...